# How can I make scss files work?

Tags: css, file, sass

I had a css file, and I added some scss code in it and I changed the extension of said file to .scss. When I refreshed my index.html file where I linked the scss one, the browser showed me plain html. What's the problem?
I know it sounds like a dumb question, but these are the type of questions that I fail to answer more often. It's like a curse. 
Please help.

Comment: You need to compile you SASS.

Comment: Sass is not compiled by the browser, you need a compiler to convert your scss files into css files.

Comment: You need to use one of these complier CodeKit (Paid) 
Compass.app (Paid, Open Source)   
Ghostlab (Paid)  
Hammer (Paid) 
Koala (Open Source)   
LiveReload (Paid, Open Source)  
**Prepros (Paid)**   
Scout-App (Free, Open Source).. As I know  **Prepros** is better compiler

Answer (score 2):

**You can't directly link from a html page to an `scss` file.** Browsers do not understand sass/scss. You need to *preprocess* it to a `css` file. (Just like source code → binary in compiler languages).

Either from command line, using the [sass command](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html), or –more conveniently– using a [build/watch-system like gulp](https://gist.github.com/sgnl/2937a3f5767a7f1b765c)…

Answer (score 1):

Your scss code need to be compiled. There are a lot of methods to compile your scss code, you can use a compiler directly via 
[command line](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html) or use some other methods, for example , I write my scss code on [Codepen.io](http://codepen.io), and when I'm finished, I just export as ZIP and I have my CSS code.